# Problems with unable to resolve hostname but IP address using CentOS 5 that is inside a XenServer

Tags: linux, dns, virtual-machine, xen, centos5

I have created a XenServer inside VirtualBox, and that I have created a VM CentOS 5 inside the XenServer, upon entering the Centos, I find myself being able to ping to my gate 192.168.43.1

And I'm able to ping to my own XenServer which is 10.0.2.15 as I'm using NAT as my network setting in my Virtual Box. My CentOS is 10.0.2.16

I'm able to ping to 8.8.8.8 but I'm unable to ping to www.google.com for some reason, my resolv.conf nameserver is also set to my dns, 192.168.43.1 and I'm able to ping to my dns, but I'm unsure why is it that I'm unable to ping to www.google.com for some reason.

resolv.conf:
[image: resolv.conf]

pinging:
[image: pinging]

Comment: I'm unable to add more pictures to support it as I do not have reputation. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use Bridged instead of NAT.also what is the output for #dig www.google.com

Comment: If I were to use bridged, it doesn't work at all.  As I need my Virtual Box to be a NAT to receive throughout the CentOS. As for the output for #dig, it will keep blinking until i press Ctrl + C/X/Z